# Angular Express fetching files from wrong url after refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am working on this small MEAN stack app, when my imaged is clicked it displays a partial with it's image info, everything works fine, but after refresh angular tries to get the app.js file from the wrong url: example: http://localhost:3000/image/56afc07d5e1fea4839791b55 it sends get request to http://localhost:3000/image which is wrong and therefore it cant find Angular app.js file.

How I am serving static files in Node:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use('/bower_components',  express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
app.use('/node_modules',  express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
app.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + "/uploads"));

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname +'/public/index.html');
});
```

This is the routing in Angular app.js:

```
app.config(function(
    $routeProvider, 
    $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/partials/main.html',
        access: {restricted: false}
    })
    .when('/signup', {
        templateUrl: '/partials/signup.html',
        controller: 'authCtrl',
        access: {restricted: false}
    })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: '/partials/login.html',
        controller: 'authCtrl',
        access: {restricted: false}
    })
    .when('/gallery', {
        templateUrl: '/partials/gallery.html',
        controller: 'authCtrl',
        access: {restricted: true}
    })
    .when('/image/:id', {
        templateUrl: '/partials/imageView.html',
        controller: 'imageViewCtrl',
        access: {restricted: true}  
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
```

**UPDATE**

Problem only occurs, when refreshing on the page with param, example: localhost:3000/image/id. No problem when refreshing on localhost:3000/image, when on localhost:3000/image/id and I reload page, it tries to get data from localhost:3000/image rather then localhost:3000

Comment: Do you have `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Yes, it's right below routing configurations.

Comment: Did you insert `<base href="" />` into document head?

Comment: I tried to use <base href="/"> and <base href="index.html">

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was very stupid. Express was routing app correctly, however in index.html file I added

Angular's app.js file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

without `"/"` before app.js therefore if url was longer then *localhost:3000/gallery* for example:

*localhost:3000/gallery/image* Angular was trying to download app.js accordingly localhost:3000/gallery.

Right way to add app.js script into index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script>
```